# Typescript. Как сделать необязательные [key:string]:string в interface

Tags: typescript, типы

Есть `interface` вида:

```
interface IDeliveryFormError {
       time?: string,
       date?: string
}
```

Как преобразовать его в нечто подобное:

```
interface IDeliveryFormError {
       [key:'time']: string,
       [key:'date']: string
}
```

Но только что бы, значения были необязательными? т.е. что бы в дальнейшем, при попытке запихнуть в объект ключ, который названием отличается от описанного в интерефейсе, TS ругался, но при этом, что бы не ругался если этот ключ отсутствует вовсе.

Быть может я некорректно задаю вопрос, поэтому скажу, что это нужно мне для использования в цикле `for in`:

```
for(let key in errors) {
    if(errors[key]) return true                                                 
}
```

Компилятор при использовании `time?: string` ругается:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IDeliveryFormError'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IDeliveryFormError'.
```

Если в интерфейсе определю `[key:string]:string` то все ок, но я бы хотел явно указать, что я жду

**дополнение вопроса**

В цикле я проверяю есть ли ключ с нужным мне значением во втором объекте и если есть - вeрнуть true

```
    interface IErrors {
           time?: string,
           date?: string
    }

    interface ITouched {
           time?: string,
           date?: string
    }



 const isFalse = (errors:IErrors,touched:Itouched) => {
    let bool = false       
         for(let key in errors) {
         if(Object.keys(touched).includes(key) && errors[key]) bool = true
      }                                                                                           
      return bool
}
```

Comment: 1) Никак, индексные сигнатуры нужны не для этого. 2) Ключи в for..in не типизируются, там всегда будет string. Вам нужно использовать приведение типов (`key as keyof typeof errors`). 3) Если нужно только проверить наличие ключа можно использовать `in`.

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо! Не могли бы вы дать ответ не в комментариях, что бы я мог определить его как ответ на вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых индексные сигнатуры так использовать нельзя, во вторых ключи в `for..in` (а так же в `Object.keys` и `Object.entries`) не типизируются и не выводятся, они всегда имеют тип `string`.

Так сделано потому что тс не может знать наверняка какие именно ключи будут в рантайме, например:

```typescript
interface A {
  a: number
}

interface B extends A {
  b: string
}

const b: B = { a: 1, b: "2" }
const a: A = b // Приводим дочерний тип к базовому

for (const key in a) { // У типа a только 1 ключ, но в рантайме их будет 2
  console.log(key)
}
```

Поэтому при использовании `for..in` необходимо явно приводить ключ к нужному типу:

```typescript
const value = a[key as keyof typeof a] // Приводим к типу ключей a
```